# Bash script. Limit user input

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos7

I was able to limit the month and year by using

```
while :
    do
    if (( 0 <  userAccPDM && userAccPDM <= 12 )); then
            accPDM=$userAccPDM && break
    else
            echo "Try again!" && read -p "Month: " userAccPDM
    fi
done
```

and

```
while :
    do
    curYr=$(date +"%Y")
    if (( userAccPDY <= curYr )); then
            accPDY=$userAccPDY && break
    else
            echo "Try again!" && read -p "Year: " userAccPDY
    fi
done
```

which means the user cannot put **0** or **13** in **Months** and put a year in **Year** greater than the current year.

I was wondering on how I can do that in **Day** like for example the user typed **2015** in **Year** and **2** in **Month** which is **February** and has only **28** days. If user put **29** in **Day**, it would be an invalid input. I hope you guys can get what I mean and sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [date](http://ss64.com/bash/date.html) to check if date is valid.

```
date "+%d/%m/%Y" -d "dd/mm/yyyy" > /dev/null 2>&1
ret=$?
```

If `ret` **is not** `0`, then date is valid

Comment: I will try this and report back if it does what I want. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll use this.